# Searching for specific characters then appending

Tags: arrays

I basically want my code to be able to search for a specific character in a list and then append it to another list depending on whether the letter was found. this is my code so far but the lists aren't appending properly

```
       list2=["apple","bannana","lychee","pear","red"]
       list3=[]
       list4=[]
       j=0

       for word in list2[:]:
         if 'R'or'Y'or'I' in word:
            list3.append(list2[j])
            j+=1
         else:
            list4.append(list2[j])
            j+=1
       print(list3)
       print(list4)
```

my output is :
["apple","bannana","lychee","pear","red"]
[]

Answer (score 0):

Your individual array elements need to be in quotes. It would be

```
list2=[“apple”, ”banana”, ”lychee”, ”pear”, “red”]
```

You also need to search for lowercase as well, as you are only searching for uppercase.

Comment: tried this but it also gives blank arrays

Comment: @Kevon Then it is because you are only searching for capital letters. you also need to search for lowercase as well.

Answer (score 0):

(Assuming you're using python, but these should be more or less applicable in other languages too)

1. When using a for-each loop (for item in list_of_items) you don't require the index, you can directly use the `item` variable.
2. You don't need the slicing (`[:]`), you can just use the list itself when you don't want a sublist.
3. Currently the `or` conditions are

   1. `'R'`
   2. `'Y'`
   3. `'I' in word`

   Due to the concept of [truthy and falsy](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/truthy-and-falsy-values-in-python/) values, the first two evaluate as true, so even though `'I' in word` is false, `'R'` and `'Y'` are true and `true or true or false` is true, so the if block is evaluated always.
4. The `in` check is case sensitive, so you need to use lower case letters to check for the condition.

Applying all these, the desired code would look something like:

```py
list2 = ["apple","bannana","lychee","pear","red"]
list3 = []
list4 = []

for word in list2:
   if 'r' in word or 'y' in word or 'i' in word:
      list3.append(word)
   else:
      list4.append(word)

print(list3)
print(list4)
```

Output:

```
['lychee', 'pear', 'red']
['apple', 'bannana']
```